# Prevent Proguard remove resource files from 3rd library

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources

I'm using `Proguard` to optimize the generated APK. The project is using a 3rd library that has files located in `resources` folder. The problem is that when i check the generated APK, the files in `resources` folder is disappeared and cause crashing when i run the application.

Even i remove the `shrinkResource` from gradle build, the problem is still there. I tried to disable `Proguard` and everything works fine.

Here is the related Proguard config for the library:

```
-keep class com.bitmark.apiservice.** {*;}
-keep class com.bitmark.cryptography.** {*;}
-keep class com.bitmark.sdk.** {*;}
```

I would like to keep the `txt` files is located inside folder `foo` but actually it been removed absolutely.